# Apache 2.4 - Debian 8 - vHost - deactivate cgi-fcgi / php-fpm use mod_php

Tags: php, apache, debian, mod-php

I try to set via vHost that cgi-fcgi / php-fpm are not used.

So in the other vHost i have that.

```
  <FilesMatch "\.php$">
     SetHandler php5-fastcgi
     Action php5-fastcgi /fastcgiphp
     Options +ExecCGI
  </FilesMatch>
```

What i have tried

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    #SetHandler php5-fastcgi
    #Action php5-fastcgi /fastcgiphp
    #Options +ExecCGI
 </FilesMatch>
```

So now it don't load fast-cgi but i want that the normal mod_php will be used now. Have someone a idea how i can handle that?

Best Regards